# 'If' Statement adding to a global variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out the user's overall percentage based on the number of tasks that they have completed. I can't seem to get the global variable to update when running the function. I want it to add one to the variable if the task is set to true, or to subtract one if false.

The function `AOAClass1();` runs everytime an item on a to-do list is clicked.

```
var userProgress = 0;
console.log("Users Progress: " + userProgress);

//Detect task class change
function AOAClass1() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;

    if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid;
    }

    if ($('#AOATask1').hasClass('checked')) {
        //Set Task To false
        var Ref = firebase.database().ref("Users/" + uid + '/Tasks');
        Ref.child("AreasOfActivity").update({
            userTask1: false,
        });

        var orginal = userProgress;
        var userProgress = orginal - 1;
    } else {
        //Set Task To true
        var Ref = firebase.database().ref("Users/" + uid + '/Tasks');
        Ref.child("AreasOfActivity").update({
            userTask1: true,
        });

        var orginal = userProgress;
        var userProgress = orginal + 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Remove the var from the userProgress update. You're overwriting the variable instead of updating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you redefine the variable using the `var` keyword:

```
var orginal = userProgress;
var userProgress = orginal - 1;
```

Omit it and it will use the global one:

```
userProgress -= 1;
```

On a different note, that's major code duplication there. You can refactor to:

```
var taskChecked = $('#AOATask1').hasClass('checked');
var Ref = firebase.database().ref("Users/" + uid + '/Tasks');
Ref.child("AreasOfActivity").update({
      userTask1: !taskChecked,
});

userProgress = taskChecked ? userProgress - 1 : userProgress + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have made the alterations and looks much cleaner now. Im not sure why but my global variable still isn't updating when the function runs?

Comment: @ConnorRoberts There might be something else then. Based on the code you wrote here and the fix it should be working.

Answer (score 2):

You must not write the `var` when accessing it. Writing the var creates a new variable in the function scope.

on line 22 and 35 remove the var

```
var userProgress = orginal - 1;
```

to

```
userProgress = orginal - 1;
```